# EnvDTE CodeClass.AddDelegate overload

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, envdte

I want to create 2 delegates with the same name but different parameters (overloaded delegate). When I try to add a delegate I get an error on the second try due to a delegate already existing. I tried to add it first with a temp name then add the parameters and then change the name so the signuature would be different but I still get an error stating that an item already exists with that name.

How can I add an overloaded delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capabilities of the code model to generate code are limited. You can try the to use EditPoint.Insert(...) to insert the code instead of using AddDelegate() method.